# Android - Check whether able to connect to server

Tags: android, performance, android-networking

I am trying to trigger an async task which post some info to the server. Before triggering the async task I need to check whether the app is able to detect the server. So I need to ping the server and  if the ping is successful, the app goes ahead with the asynctask.

Can anybody let me know which is the efficient way to ping the server to ensure the app is able to connect to the server. I have the IP and the port of the server.

I used socket code to accomplish this task 
    **Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 8080);**

But the response is poor when the server is down. The app freezes and then gives the message ( which is a custom message I have built) that the server is down.

Is there a more elegant way to get to know the app can communicate with the server apart from using the HttpURLconnection and by only using the IP name and the port of the server.

Any info will be very helpful. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut)
```

Something like this?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried this. I am testing in my local machine. How to make sure that the local machine accepts input from port 8080. Also, I have the IP as 192.168.1.1. How to change it to hostname?